# I want to convert equations from Word to Latex

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I'm trying to convert my equations I make in Microsoft Office Word 2013 to latex.
Because I would like to post my equations I make in word at math.stackexchange.com.

I'm able to convert it to MathML. But if I post it here it doesn't really look like it should be, for example:

```
<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"><mml:mtable><mml:mtr><mml:mtd><mml:mrow><mml:maligngroup/><mml:mi>a</mml:mi><mml:mo>&lt;</mml:mo><mml:mi>x</mml:mi><mml:mo>&lt;</mml:mo><mml:mi>a</mml:mi><mml:mo>+</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>δ</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:malignmark/><mml:mo>⇒</mml:mo><mml:mfenced open="|" close="|" separators="|"><mml:mrow><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>f</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mfenced separators="|"><mml:mrow><mml:mi>x</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:mfenced><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:mrow></mml:mfenced><mml:mo>&lt;</mml:mo><mml:mfrac><mml:mrow><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:mfrac></mml:mrow></mml:mtd></mml:mtr><mml:mtr><mml:mtd><mml:mrow><mml:maligngroup/><mml:malignmark/><mml:mo>⇒</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:mfrac><mml:mrow><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:mfrac><mml:mo>&lt;</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>f</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mfenced separators="|"><mml:mrow><mml:mi>x</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:mfenced><mml:mo>&lt;</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>+</mml:mo><mml:mfrac><mml:mrow><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:mfrac></mml:mrow></mml:mtd></mml:mtr><mml:mtr><mml:mtd><mml:mrow><mml:maligngroup/><mml:malignmark/><mml:mo>⇒</mml:mo><mml:mfrac><mml:mrow><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>+</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>L</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:mfrac><mml:mo>&lt;</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>f</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>(</mml:mo><mml:mi>x</mml:mi><mml:mo>)</mml:mo></mml:mrow></mml:mtd></mml:mtr></mml:mtable><mml:mi> </mml:mi></mml:math>
```

a<x<a+δ1⇒f1x-L1<L1-L22⇒L1-L1-L22<f1x<L1+L1-L22⇒L1+L22<f1(x)

It should look like this:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8FEA31C0ACCF70F0!135

Comment: You should visit http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why don't you use a converter?

Answer (score 8):

Here is my recommended way:

1. Delete the question in word.
2. Rewrite the equation in LaTex.

Seriously, if you want to use M.SE regularly, you will be much more efficient if you know basic LaTex. Even more so if you actually want to write serious mathematical texts eventually.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, you might find some advice at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

- [Converting MS Word mathtype to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24089/converting-ms-word-mathtype-to-latex)
- [How can I convert from Microsoft Word to a LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document)
- [How can I import an exam or assignment from Word into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-import-an-exam-or-assignment-from-word-into-latex)